# c# Protected base class only used for inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance

Struggling a bit with inheritance here. I have common properties to use in two derived classes, so I made a base class `LogBaseViewModel`. I don't ever want this base class to be used except to be inherited by derived classes, so I made it protected (also tried private).

I found this bit, and maybe I'm mis-interpreting, but thought if I wrapped all 3 of these classes within one, they'd no longer be "outside" and hence this would be allowed.

From section 3.5.3 of the C# 5 specification:

> When a protected instance member is accessed outside the program text
>   of the class in which it is declared, and when a protected internal
>   instance member is accessed outside the program text of the program in
>   which it is declared, the access must take place within a class
>   declaration that derives from the class in which it is declared.
>   Furthermore, the access is required to take place through an instance
>   of that derived class type or a class type constructed from it.

However, no joy, I get the error: `Error CS0060 Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'LogViewModels.LogBaseViewModel' is less accessible than class 'LogViewModels.LogSearchViewModel'`.

```
public class LogViewModels
{
    protected class LogBaseViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Level { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public string Exception { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogSearchViewModel : LogBaseViewModel
    {

        public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogViewModel : LogBaseViewModel
    {
        public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I don't ever want this base class to be used except to be inherited by derived classes" That sounds like a perfect candidate for an abstract class.

Comment: @Sweeper thanks! So all I had to do was to add the `abstract` modifier to the base class. Easy enough. Do you want to make a quick answer as such so I can accept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying the `protected` modifier on `LogBaseViewModel` would make it accessible only inside `LogViewModels`, and in *subclasses of `LogViewModels`*, not subclasses of `LogBaseViewModel`.

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/protected):

> A protected member is accessible within its class and by derived class instances.

The "protected member" is the *class* `LogBaseViewModel`. "Its class" refers to the enclosing class `LogViewModels`.

By making `LogBaseViewModel` protected, you are telling the compiler that you don't want any external class to know about the insides of `LogBaseViewModel`. But then you said `public class LogSearchViewModel : LogBaseViewModel`. This allows people to access the insides of `LogBaseViewModel` through `LogSearchViewModel`! The compiler sees that this will make the `protected` modifier on `LogBaseViewModel` meaningless, so it gives you an error.

You said:

> I don't ever want this base class to be used except to be inherited by derived classes.

Which is the use case for an [`abstract` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract). You should keep `LogBaseViewModel` public, and make it `abstract`.